# Checkbox with default value

Tags: angularjs, forms

I want to have a checked checkbox on init. Here's my HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" name="orderForm" novalidate>
  <input type="radio" id="service-professional" name="service-type" value="Professional" class="service-input" ng-model="orderForm.serviceType" ng-change="setService(value)" />
  <input type="radio" id="service-premium" name="service-type" value="Premium" class="service-input" ng-model="orderForm.serviceType" ng-change="setService(value)" />
</form>
```

And my controller:

```
// initializes the form
$scope.orderForm = {};

$scope.orderForm.serviceType = {
  // how to set Premium as default?
};
```

I tried many things in `$scope.orderForm.serviceType`, but for the sake of me, can't figure it out.

Can you explain how to set Premium as the default checked option? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.orderForm = {
  serviceType: 'Professional'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
// initializes the form
$scope.orderForm = {};

$scope.orderForm.serviceType = 'Premium';
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply use this ->
  ng-checked="your_model == 'your value'" ,

```
<input type="radio" id="service-professional" name="service-type" ng-true-value="1" value="Professional" ng-false-value="0" ng-checked="orderForm.serviceType == 'Professional'" class="service-input" ng-model="orderForm.serviceType" ng-change="setService(value)" />
<input type="radio" id="service-premium" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-checked="orderForm.serviceType == 'Premium'" name="service-type" value="Premium" class="service-input" ng-model="orderForm.serviceType" ng-change="setService(value)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set default value for your checkbox scope using **ng-init**
ex: in html add **ng-init="scopeName = 'value'"** than use it **scopeName** in your checkbox ng-model as well as ng-checked

**see below code**

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" name="orderForm" novalidate ng-init="orderForm.serviceType="1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="service-professional" name="service-type" value="Professional" class="service-input" ng-model="orderForm.serviceType" ng-change="setService(value)" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="service-premium" name="service-type" value="Premium" class="service-input" ng-model="orderForm.serviceType" ng-change="setService(value)" />
</form>
```